# What does CQ5's Placeholder.getDefaultPlaceholder exactly do?

Tags: aem

The [API docs](http://bit.ly/1lhUyVK) are not much descriptive:

> Get default placeholder for any component incl. title as text information

Here's the method signature:

```
public static String getDefaultPlaceholder(ServletRequest slingRequest,
                                           Component component,
                                           String defaultPlaceholder)
```

1. What's a Placeholder? What is/should be returned by `getDefaultPlaceholder`?
2. What's the purpose of `defaultPlaceholder`? What should I pass as `defaultPlaceholder`? What would happen if I pass `null`?

Answer (score 0):

When a component does not have any content defined you need to put a placeholder to occupy its place (for the editor to know there's a component there).
The getDefaultComponent returns a  HTML snippet that works as the placeholder. It consists of an empty div with attributes class and data-emptytext with the title of the component as its value.

```
<div class="" data-emptyText="component.getTitle()"></div>
```

You can also pass an additional parameter with a list of strings and they will be added in the class attribute of the div.

```
getDefaultPlaceholder(ServletRequest slingRequest,
                      Component component,
                      String defaultPlaceholder,
                      String... addClasses)
```